# parent grease pencil to object

Tags: rigging, grease-pencil, 2d

I am trying to rig a simple puppet to facilitate some 2D drawing in perspective. So I would like du draw some shapes on this puppet that would follow the movement and position in 3D space. But I have some problem to parent my grease pencil strokes. As you can see in the picture below my grease pencil drawn on object surface is parented to the head object mesh (if I move the object the grease pencil moves too). My object mesh is also rigged. As I rotate the bone, the head mesh rotate too. But in this cas the grease pencil do not. I have tried to parent my grease pencil layer to the bones or the mesh. It is not working :-( anyone has already encountered this issue?

[image]

Comment: I am able to move both my head mesh and my grease pencil with when I parent my grease pencil using "set parent to vertex". But my grease pencil moves from its position in the 3D scene :-( Maybe I could find a solution by changing the center of shape or something like that?

Comment: My mistake. I parent both my mesh and my grease to my bone. Everything is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Put the armature modifier in the Grease pencil. Create a Vertex group on it with the same name the bone you want to make it move. Done

[image]